# Wait for Plink -batch command to finish

Tags: python, batch-file, plink

I have a Python script (on windows box) that makes a call to a .bat file on the same Windows box.  Right now I am using subprocess.check_call (Python 3.5)

That .bat file makes a call to a Linux box using pLink.

pLink uses SSH and a -batch stack of commands which results in the execution of a shell script

I need a way to WAIT for the shell script to complete.

I have tried sleeps in the plink cmds, -N, different Python approaches (popen, call, check_call, while true on the output file name, etc,), without success.  Right now, it blows through the process and uploads the expected output file with  0 volume, due to the script still running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have spent way too much time on this already.

Comment: Have any code you wish to share for the three different scripting languages you are using?

Comment: Yes, show us some code. And also consider using a native Python SSH library (like Paramiko), instead of driving an external console application.

Answer (score 0):

Success.  The shell script on the Linux box uses a proprietary java executer JAR file to execute a job.  That executer has a an option, -w wait.  Once I implemented that everything worked.

Here is a summary of the code flow inside of the FME ETL Tool

Python

```
import fme
import fmeobjects
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, check_call
import os
import time

def dosomething(feature):
    try:
        subprocess.check_call("X:\\scripts\\gis\\Geocode\\gc\\exec_gc " + feature.getAttribute('INPUT_FILE_NM') + " " + feature.getAttribute('OUTPUT_FILE_NM'), shell=True, stdin=open(os.devnull) )
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        raise fmeobjects.FMEException('Geocoder Error')
```

BAT file:

```
plink -ssh userid@linuxbox -pw secret -batch "sudo su - specialuserid; cd ../../opt/dir2/scripts; ./Dynamic_GC_Job.ksh %1 %2; exit"
```